# Unable to include a thesis reference

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to include a thesis reference, but not able to do it. The MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{IEEEtran}


\begin{document}
hi

\cite{mythesis}

\end{document}
```

In the .bbl file, the reference is included as follows:

```
@MASTERSTHESIS{mythesis,
  AUTHOR =       {myname},
  TITLE =        {mytitle},
  SCHOOL =       {university},
  YEAR =         {2013},
  month =        {may},
  }
```

In the .pdf output, the reference is always gives as [?]

Comment: Are you compiling the files in the suggested sequence? latex, bibtex, latex, latex?

Comment: Also you mention the reference in the .bbl file. That seems to be wrong, it should be in a .bib file. A .bbl file is generated when you run bibtex.

Comment: The `.tex` file you provide above has no way of knowing where to find this citation (which should [in that form] be in a `.bib` file, *not* a `.bbl`).  You probably need to add: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{<name of your bibfile>}`, or something like that.  Then you need to run a sequence of `latex-bibtex-latex-latex` (or `pdflatex`) as mentioned already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a little more assistance in order for the references to show up:

[image]

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{IEEEtran}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents

\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{thesis.bib}
@MASTERSTHESIS{mythesis,
  AUTHOR =       {myname},
  TITLE =        {mytitle},
  SCHOOL =       {university},
  YEAR =         {2013},
  month =        {may},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
hi \cite{mythesis}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

Now follow these steps:

1. Compile using (PDF)LaTeX which will produce `thesis.bib` as well as a `.aux` file. The `.aux` file is requesting a citation called `mythesis`, which doesn't exist anywhere (according to LaTeX, that is).
2. Compile using BibTeX. This will produce a `.bbl` file based on your `.aux` and `thesis.bib`.
3. Compile using (PDF)LaTeX again which will now have a valid `.bbl` file containing the relevant bibliography information in it:

   ```
   % Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.13 (2008/09/30)
   \begin{thebibliography}{1}
   \providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
   \csname url@samestyle\endcsname
   \providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
   \providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
   \providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
   \providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
   \providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
   \BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
     \fontdimen4\font\relax}
   \providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
   \typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
   \typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
   \typeout{** the default language instead.}%
   \else
   \language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
   \fi
   #2}}
   \providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
   \BIBdecl

   \bibitem{mythesis}
   myname, ``mytitle,'' Master's thesis, university, may 2013.

   \end{thebibliography}
   ```

   Essentially, BibTeX produces a `thebibliography` environment that can be included in your document.
4. (optional) Compile with (PDF)LaTeX to make any references settle after the citations are valid.